# Filtering list elements based on range of value

Tags: haskell

I have a list declared:

```
lst = [-1,6,4,13]
```

and i want to filter the list elements with values > 0 and less than 10. I wrote:

```
filterList :: [Int] -> [Int]
filterList lst = filter (>0 && <10) lst
```

When i run :t filter i can see that:

```
filter (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

But when i run the compiler, the error shown is due to "<10" in the filter clause. Is this not the right way to filter as I specified that i want to filter values more than zero and less than 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> filterList lst = filter (>0 && <10) lst

The problem is that it's not a valid expression in Haskell. But even if we add parentheses to get rid of parse errors:

```
filterList lst = filter ((>0) && (<10)) lst -- no parse errors, but types are not matched
```

we'll get the error message, that types are not matched, which is correct, since `&&` expects both arguments to be `Bool`, but `(> 0)` and `(< 10)` are functions `Integer -> Bool`.

Seems the functions lack arguments, but we can provide some:

```
filterList lst = filter (\x -> (x > 0) && (x < 10)) lst
```

Comment: so the 'x' is necessary in the lambda expression.

Comment: @Maxxx Well, you could write it in pointfree style as `filter ((&&) <$> (>0) <*> (<10)) lst` or `filter (liftA2 (&&) (>0) (<10)) lst` using applicatives, but the lambda is simpler

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
[x | x <- lst, x<10, x>0]
```

Or perhaps the built in filter function twice.

```
filter (< 10) (filter (> 0) lst)
```